# How to use multiple tmLanguage files in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am creating a language extension in **vscode** for myself. Because it will associate with different file types, I plan to make different tmlanguge files for specific rules. According to [this](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars), I could extend the `scopeName` to achieve that.

So I created in my `./package.json` files something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "tst",
    "displayName": "Test Language",
    "description": "A test for language extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.34.0"
    },
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "tst",
            "aliases": ["Test", "tst"],
            "extensions": [".tst",".type1",".type2"],
            "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
        }],
        "grammars": [{
            "language": "tst",
            "scopeName": "source.tst",
            "path": "./syntaxes/tst.tmLanguage.json"
        },
        {
            "scopeName": "source.tst.type1",
            "path": "./syntaxes/type1.tmLanguage.json"
        },
        {
            "scopeName": "source.tst.type2",
            "path": "./syntaxes/type2.tmLanguage.json"
        }]
    }
}
```

Then I create the base rules in `./syntaxes/tst.tmLanguage.json` and both `.type1` and `.type2` have been applied with my grammars.

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "test",
            "name": "constant.character"
        }
    ],
    "scopeName": "source.tst"
}
```

Afterwards I also make `./syntaxes/type1.tmLanguage.json` something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "type1",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "type1",
            "name": "constant.language"
        }
    ],  
    "scopeName": "source.tst.type1"
}
```

Nothing works for any rules in `.type1`.

[image]

I hope both file in the picture can recognize **`test`** and **`type1`**.
I checked the vscode pre-installed cpp language extension.
They also use scopeName for `source.c` and `source.c.platform`.
I guess it is for the similar purpose?

Did I overlook something?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use these scopes from different `tmLanguage` files in the main grammar, you have to explicitly `include` them:

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "match": "test",
            "name": "constant.character"
        },
        {
            "include": "source.tst.type1"
        },
        {
            "include": "source.tst.type2"
        }
    ],
    "scopeName": "source.tst"
}
```

[image]

---

Regarding the built-in cpp extension and `platform.tmLanguage.json` - as far as I can tell, it's not actively being used by the c and cpp grammars. There's this comment in `cpp/build/update-grammars.js`:

```js
// `source.c.platform` which is still included by other grammars
```

So that sounds more like a backwards-compatibility measure in case any third-party grammars still use it.

Comment: Thanks again! I will test it after holiday. But I believe it is just what I need.